# Comparison of R, statmodels, sklearn for a classification task with logistic regression

Tags: python, r, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I have made some experiments with logistic regression in R, python statmodels and sklearn. While the results given by R and statmodels agree, there is some discrepency with what is returned by sklearn. I would like to understand why these results are different. 
I understand that it is probably not the same optimization algorithms that are used under the wood.

Specifically, I use the standard `Default` dataset (used in the [ISL book](http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/)). The following Python code reads the data into a dataframe `Default`.

```
import pandas as pd
 # data is available here
Default = pd.read_csv('https://d1pqsl2386xqi9.cloudfront.net/notebooks/Default.csv', index_col=0)
 #
Default['default']=Default['default'].map({'No':0, 'Yes':1})
Default['student']=Default['student'].map({'No':0, 'Yes':1})
 #
I=Default['default']==0
print("Number of 'default' values :", Default[~I]['balance'].count())
```

Number of 'default' values : 333.

There is a total of 10000 examples, with only 333 positives

### Logistic regression in R

I use the following

```
library("ISLR")
data(Default,package='ISLR')
 #write.csv(Default,"default.csv")
glm.out=glm('default~balance+income+student', family=binomial, data=Default)
s=summary(glm.out)
print(s)
#
glm.probs=predict(glm.out,type="response") 
glm.probs[1:5]
glm.pred=ifelse(glm.probs>0.5,"Yes","No")
 #attach(Default)
t=table(glm.pred,Default$default)
print(t)
score=mean(glm.pred==Default$default)
print(paste("score",score))
```

The result is as follows

> Call: glm(formula = "default~balance+income+student", family =
>   binomial, 
>       data = Default)
>
> Deviance Residuals: 
>       Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max
>   -2.4691  -0.1418  -0.0557  -0.0203   3.7383
>
> Coefficients:
>
> ```
> Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)        
> (Intercept) -1.087e+01  4.923e-01 -22.080  < 2e-16 
> balance      5.737e-03    2.319e-04  24.738  < 2e-16  
> income       3.033e-06  8.203e-06   0.370   0.71152     
> studentYes  -6.468e-01  2.363e-01  -2.738  0.00619
> ```
>
> (Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)
>
> ```
> Null deviance: 2920.6  on 9999  degrees of freedom Residual
> ```
>
> deviance: 1571.5  on 9996  degrees of freedom AIC: 1579.5
>
> Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 8
>
> ```
>      glm.pred   No  Yes
>  No  9627  228
>  Yes   40  105
> ```
>
> [1](http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/) "score 0.9732"

I am too lazy to cut and paste the results obtained with statmodels. It suffice to say that they are extremely similar to those given by R.

### sklearn

For sklearn, I ran the following code.

- There is a parameter class_weight for taking into account unbalanced classes. I tested class_weight=None (no weightening -- I think that is the default in R), and class_weight='auto' (weightening with the inverse frequencies found inthe data)
- I also put C=10000,the inverse of the regularization parameter, so as to minimize the effect of regularization.

~~

```
import sklearn
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

features = Default[[ 'balance', 'income' ]]
target = Default['default']
# 
for weight in (None,  'auto'):
    print("*"*40+"\nweight:",weight)

    classifier = LogisticRegression(C=10000, class_weight=weight, random_state=42) 
                #C=10000 ~ no regularization

    classifier.fit(features, target,)  #fit classifier on whole base
    print("Intercept", classifier.intercept_)
    print("Coefficients", classifier.coef_)

    y_true=target
    y_pred_cls=classifier.predict_proba(features)[:,1]>0.5
    C=confusion_matrix(y_true,y_pred_cls)

    score=(C[0,0]+C[1,1])/(C[0,0]+C[1,1]+C[0,1]+C[1,0])
    precision=(C[1,1])/(C[1,1]+C[0 ,1])
    recall=(C[1,1])/(C[1,1]+C[1,0])
    print("\n Confusion matrix")
    print(C)
    print()
    print('{s:{c}<{n}}{num:2.4}'.format(s='Score',n=15,c='', num=score))
    print('{s:{c}<{n}}{num:2.4}'.format(s='Precision',n=15,c='', num=precision))
    print('{s:{c}<{n}}{num:2.4}'.format(s='Recall',n=15,c='', num=recall))
```

The results are given below.

```
> **************************************** 
>weight: None 
>
>Intercept [ -1.94164126e-06] 
>
>Coefficients [[ 0.00040756 -0.00012588]]
> 
>  Confusion matrix 
>
>     [[9664    3]  
>     [ 333    0]]
> 
>     Score          0.9664 
>     Precision      0.0 
>     Recall         0.0
>
> **************************************** 
>weight: auto 
>
>Intercept [-8.15376429] 
>
>Coefficients 
>[[  5.67564834e-03   1.95253338e-05]]
> 
>  Confusion matrix 
>
>     [[8356 1311]  
>     [  34  299]]
> 
>     Score          0.8655 
>     Precision      0.1857 
>     Recall         0.8979
```

What I observe is that for `class_weight=None`, the Score is excellent but **no** positive example is recognized. Precision and recall are at zero. The coefficients found are **very** small, particularly the intercept. Modifying C does not change things. 
For `class_weight='auto'` things seems better but I still have a precision which is very low (too much positive classified). 
Again, changing C does not help. If I modify the intercept by hand, I can recover the results given by R. So I suspect that here is a discrepency between the estimation of the intecepts in the two cases. As this has a consequence in the specification of the threeshold (analog to a resampling of pulations), this can explain the differences in performances.

However, I would welcome any advice for the choice between the two solutions and help to understand the origin of these differences. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into a similar issue and ended up [posting about it on /r/MachineLearning](http://www.reddit.com/r/MachineLearning/comments/3bbijy/why_is_a_simple_logistic_regression_model/). It turns out the difference can be attributed to data standardization. Whatever approach scikit-learn is using to find the parameters of the model will yield better results if the data is standardized. scikit-learn has some documentation discussing preprocessing data (including standardization), which can be found [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html).

## Results

```
Number of 'default' values : 333
Intercept: [-6.12556565]
Coefficients: [[ 2.73145133  0.27750788]]

Confusion matrix
[[9629   38]
 [ 225  108]]

Score          0.9737
Precision      0.7397
Recall         0.3243
```

## Code

```
# scikit-learn vs. R
# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28747019/comparison-of-r-statmodels-sklearn-for-a-classification-task-with-logistic-reg

import pandas as pd
import sklearn

from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn import preprocessing

# Data is available here.
Default = pd.read_csv('https://d1pqsl2386xqi9.cloudfront.net/notebooks/Default.csv', index_col = 0)

Default['default'] = Default['default'].map({'No':0, 'Yes':1})
Default['student'] = Default['student'].map({'No':0, 'Yes':1})

I = Default['default'] == 0
print("Number of 'default' values : {0}".format(Default[~I]['balance'].count()))

feats = ['balance', 'income']

Default[feats] = preprocessing.scale(Default[feats])

# C = 1e6 ~ no regularization.
classifier = LogisticRegression(C = 1e6, random_state = 42) 

classifier.fit(Default[feats], Default['default'])  #fit classifier on whole base
print("Intercept: {0}".format(classifier.intercept_))
print("Coefficients: {0}".format(classifier.coef_))

y_true = Default['default']
y_pred_cls = classifier.predict_proba(Default[feats])[:,1] > 0.5

confusion = confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred_cls)
score = float((confusion[0, 0] + confusion[1, 1])) / float((confusion[0, 0] + confusion[1, 1] + confusion[0, 1] + confusion[1, 0]))
precision = float((confusion[1, 1])) / float((confusion[1, 1] + confusion[0, 1]))
recall = float((confusion[1, 1])) / float((confusion[1, 1] + confusion[1, 0]))
print("\nConfusion matrix")
print(confusion)
print('\n{s:{c}<{n}}{num:2.4}'.format(s = 'Score', n = 15, c = '', num = score))
print('{s:{c}<{n}}{num:2.4}'.format(s = 'Precision', n = 15, c = '', num = precision))
print('{s:{c}<{n}}{num:2.4}'.format(s = 'Recall', n = 15, c = '', num = recall))
```

Comment: Thanks. I should have find it myself. This is useful to know.

Answer (score 6):

Although this post is old, I wanted to give you a solution. In your post you are comparing apples with oranges. In your R code, you are estimating "balance, income, and student" on "default". In your Python code, you are only estimating "balance and income" on "default". Of course, you cannot get the same estimates.
Also the differences cannot be attributed to feature scaling, as logistic regression usually does not need it in comparison to kmeans.

You are right to set a high C, so that there is no regularization. If you want to have the same output as in R, you have to change the solver to "newton-cg". Different solvers can give different results but they still yield the same objective value. As long as your solver converge everything will be okay.

Here's the code that give you the same estimates like in R and Statsmodels:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from patsy import dmatrices # 
import numpy as np

 # data is available here
Default = pd.read_csv('https://d1pqsl2386xqi9.cloudfront.net/notebooks/Default.csv', index_col=0)
 #
Default['default']=Default['default'].map({'No':0, 'Yes':1})
Default['student']=Default['student'].map({'No':0, 'Yes':1})

# use dmatrices to get data frame for logistic regression
y, X = dmatrices('default ~ balance+income+C(student)',
                  Default,return_type="dataframe")

y = np.ravel(y)

# fit logistic regression
model = LogisticRegression(C = 1e6, fit_intercept=False, solver = "newton-cg", max_iter=10000000)
model = model.fit(X, y)

# examine the coefficients
pd.DataFrame(zip(X.columns, np.transpose(model.coef_)))
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. You are right for the fact that I forgot the 'student' feature in the scikit-learn experiment. I realized that shortly. However as you can check, this gives a very very small variation on the result and does not change the problem.

Comment: (continued) 
As the previous commenter indicated, preconditioning the features helps and yields the same results as R. This can be checked by running the code and comparing the outputs. 
You are also right when you suggest to change ths solver. This also yiels to the same results as R. 

The point is probably that the problem is badly conditioned for the standard liblinear solver that does not converge to the true solution (but it seems to converge). Preconditioning or changing to another (better in this case) solver yield a correct result.